# Call mutable method on value from mutable struct field

Tags: data-structures, rust, borrow-checker

I'm still a bit new to Rust, so I'm not quite sure how to restructure my code properly to make what I'm trying to do possible. [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c7a0952cf2e242d22544b3d074bcf359)'s a link to an MCVE of the code I'm running.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is iterate through a vector of entities and get an action from each of them. I don't need a mutable borrow for that part specifically, but I do need to pass a mutable reference to `self` into a method later in the function to perform the action that was returned.

Here's the exact error message I'm getting:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:16:72
   |
16 |             let action = self.entities[self.current_entity].get_action(self);
   |                          -------------                      ---------- ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
   |                          |                                  |
   |                          |                                  mutable borrow later used by call
   |                          mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

How should I structure my code so that what I'm trying to do is possible?

Comment: @SCappella: Wow, that's super helpful. What's even better is it also taught me why it's not allowed, alongside several workable solutions. I'm heading off to bed, but once I get back to the code I'll post whatever I end up using for posterity, if there isn't a working answer by then. Which of those solutions do you think is the best?

Answer (score 1):

I split up line 16 from your example to explain what (I think) is going on:

I.e. from

```
let action = self.entities[self.current_entity].get_action(self);
```

to:

```
let entity = &mut self.entities[self.current_entity];
let action = entity.get_action(self);
```

In the above, `entity` mutably refers to `self` (indirectly through `self.entities`). Thus, `get_action` cannot modify `self` because it could - in particular - change `self.entities`, thereby invalidating the reference `entity`. This is not allowed by (safe) Rust.

You could try to split up your `Level` into `entities` and `noentities`. This allows you to explicitly specify which parts of `Level` are actually mutably referred to. (See https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a8199f0bd4f8119f2ec1e79f9ebb542d for an updated example.)

I.e. you'd have

```
struct LevelNoEntities {
    current_entity: usize,
    foo: i32,
}
struct Level {
    entities: Vec<Entity>,
    noentities: LevelNoEntities,
}
```

Then, you would now have the following:

```
let entity = &mut self.entities[self.noentities.current_entity];
let action = entity.get_action(&self.noentities);
```

Now, `entity` only refers to `self.entities`, and you can still pass `noentities` around because the compiler now knows you mutably refer to only a part of `Level`.